# ExtJS 5 Chained DataStore Example: KitchenSink is not defined

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to port the Chained DataStore example into my existing Ext app. From this KitchenSink [example](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#binding-chained-stores) I placed the source code below into Ext.application and get 'KitchenSink is not defined. Where does KitchenSink get defined? I thought KitchenSink was part of a package name before but is it being referenced as a singleton in this example?

`Ext.application({
    name: 'testApp',
    stores: {
        everyone: {
            model: 'Person',
            data: KitchenSink.model.Person.generateData(15, 10)
        },
        adults: {
            source: '{everyone}',
            filters: [{
                property: 'age',
                value: 18,
                operator: '>='
            }],
            sorters: [{
                property: 'age',
                direction: 'ASC'
            }]
        }
    }
  });`'

Comment: The stores declared in a viewmodel are not the same as those for an application, see: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-stores

Answer (score 0):

The example you've referenced also includes a model named `KitchenSink.model.Person` which you haven't included. The reference in the code you posted to `KitchenSink.model.Person.generateData(15, 10)` fills the store with randomly generated Person models.

You'll need to copy the View, ViewModel, ViewController and Model from this example if you want it to run without edits.